# Azure Table Storage transaction limitations

Tags: azure, storage, azure-table-storage

I'm running performance tests against ATS and its behaving a bit weird when using multiple virtual machines against the same table / storage account.

The entire pipeline is non blocking (await/async) and using TPL for concurrent and parallel execution.

First of all its very strange that with this setup i'm only getting about 1200 insertions. This is running on a L VM box, that is 4 cores + 800mbps.

I'm inserting 100.000 rows with unique PK and unique RK, that should leverage the ultimate distribution.

Even more deterministic behavior is the following.

When I run 1 VM i get about 1200 insertions per second.
When I run 3 VM i get about 730 on each insertions per second.

Its quite humors to read the blog post where they are specifying their targets.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/windows-azures-flat-network-storage-and-2012-scalability-targets/

> Single Table Partition– a table partition are all of the entities in a table with the      same partition key value, and usually tables have many partitions. The throughput target   for a single table partition is:
>
> Up to 2,000 entities per second
>
> Note, this is for a single partition, and not a single table. Therefore, a table with     good partitioning, can process up to the 20,000 entities/second, which is the overall account target described above.

What shall I do to be able to utilize the 20k per second, and how would it be possible to execute more than 1,2k per VM?

--

Update:

I've now also tried using 3 storage accounts for each individual node and is still getting the performance / throttling behavior. Which i can't find a logical reason for.

--

Update 2:

I've optimized the code further and now i'm possible to execute about 1550.

--

Update 3:

I've now also tried in US West. The performance is worse there. About 33% lower.

--

Update 4:

I tried executing the code from a XL machine. Which is 8 cores instead of 4 and the double amount of memory and bandwidth and got a 2% increase in performance so clearly this problem is not on my side..

Comment: Good one @SimonMunro, adding :)

Comment: Unlikely to be the answer, but... Have you just recently created the storage account you are using or have you had it a while? There was something about this higher performance target only working on storage accounts created after a certain date.

Comment: Yes it was newly created @Frans

Comment: How peculiar. Have starred the question - I am intrigued now :)

Comment: Are you going directly against the REST API, or are you using one of the client wrappers (.NET library since you mention you are using the TPL for parallelization)?

Comment: Yes we are using the .NET wrapper. We have been thinking of doing a pure socket based implementation to see if there is any constraint on the client lib. But as long as our CPU is saturated or bandwidth i don't really feel that it makes sense. @MikeWo

Answer (score 4):

A few comments:

1. You mention that you are using unique PK/RK to get ultimate
   distribution, but you have to keep in mind that the PK balancing is
   not immediate.  When you first create a table, the entire table will
   be served by 1 partition server.  So if you are doing inserts across
   several different PKs, they will still be going to one partition
   server and be bottlenecked by the scalability target for a single
   partition.  The partition master will only start splitting your
   partitions among multiple partition servers after it has identified hot
   partition servers.  In your <2 minute test you will not see the
   benefit of multiple partiton servers or PKs.  The throughput in the
   article is targeted towards a well distributed PK scheme with
   frequently accessed data, causing the data to be divided amongst
   multiple partition servers.
2. The size of your VM is not the issue as
   you are not blocked on CPU, Memory, or Bandwidth.  You can achieve
   full storage performance from a small VM size.
3. Check out
   http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/5c8189b9-53aa-4d6a-a086-013d927e15a7/default.aspx.
   I just now did a quick test using that tool from a WebRole VM in the
   same datacenter as my storage account and I acheived, from a single
   instance of the tool on a single VM, ~2800 items per second upload
   and ~7300 items per second download.  This is using 1024 byte
   entities, 10 threads, and 100 batch size.  I don't know how efficient this tool is or if it disables Nagles Algorithm as I was unable to get great results (I got ~1000/second) using a batch size of 1, but at least with the 100 batch size it shows that you can achieve high items/second.  This was done in US West.
4. Are you using Storage client library 1.7 (Microsoft.Azure.StorageClient.dll) or 2.0 (Microsoft.Azure.Storage.dll)?  The 2.0 library has some performance improvements and should yield better results.

Comment: Hey! Do you got any example from this quote, how to achive this? "The size of your VM is not the issue as you are not blocked on CPU, Memory, or Bandwidth. You can achieve full storage performance from a small VM size."

Comment: I know this is a bit of a necro comment coming two years later... but your first point about PK balancing not being immediate is extremely interesting.

I spent 4 hours last night optimising a bulk table insert routine... I was tearing down and re-creating the storage table every run on a relatively small run of 100k entities, ~30 rows per PK, maxing out at 5000 entities per second. Will be very interested to see if this changes later when I consider the partitioning delay.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this may have to do with TCP Nagle.
See [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/06/25/nagle-s-algorithm-is-not-friendly-towards-small-requests.aspx) and [this blog post](http://robertgreiner.com/2012/06/why-is-azure-table-storage-so-slow/).

In essence, TCP Nagle is a protocol-level optimization that batches up small requests. Since you are sending lots of small requests this is likely to negatively affect your performance.

You can disable TCP Nagle by executing this code when starting your application

```
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
```

Comment: Already done. And i've tried with both approaches and yes using NaggleAltorithm is slower. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are the compute instances and storage account in the same affinity group? Affinity groups ensure that network proximity between the services is optimal and should result in lower latency at the network level.

You can find affinity group configuration under the network tab.

Comment: The virtual machines are in preview and doesn't seem to allow setting or initializing with a affinity group. I'm gonna try to setup a worker role and rdp to it and then run the tests without the affinity group and look at the result

Comment: Yes, you can.. the name is just different, they call it virtual network there. But should be the same thing.

Comment: Ah allright, right now i'm setting up a worker role anyway and running tests against a storage account within the same affinity group.

Comment: Tried it now, same machine size. And with affinity group. Performance is worse. 1100 instead of 1500. I've ran the tests 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to believe that the maximum throughput is for an optimized load. For example, I bet you that you can achieve higher performance using Batch requests than individual requests you are doing now. And of course, if you use GUIDs for your PK, you can't Batch in your current test.

So what if you changed your test to batch insert entities in groups of 100 (maximum per batch), still using GUIDs, but for which 100 entities would have the same PK?

Comment: Sure, I'm gonna give it a try even though its appropriate for our use-case.