# Azure Table Increased Latency

Tags: performance, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to create an app which can efficiently write data into Azure Table. In order to test storage performance, I created a simple console app, which sends hardcoded entities in a loop. Each entry is 0.1 kByte. Data is sent in batches (100 items in each batch, 10 kBytes each batch). For every batch, I prepare entries with the same partition key, which is generated by incrementing a global counter - so I never send more than one request to the same partition. Also, I control a degree of parallelism by increasing/decreasing the number of threads. Each thread sends batches synchronously (no request overlapping).
If I use 1 thread, I see 5 requests per second (5 batches, 500 entities). At that time Azure portal metrics shows table latency below 100ms - which is quite good.
If I increase the number of treads up to 12 I see x12 increase in outgoing requests. This rate stays stable for a few minutes. But then, for some reason I start being throttled - I see latency increase and requests amount drop.

Below you can see account metrics - highlighted point shows 2K31 transactions (batches) per minute. It is 3850 entries per second. If threads are increased up to 50, then latency increases up to 4 seconds, and transaction rate drops to 700 requests per second.

[image: account metrics]

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-scalability-targets), I should be able to send up to 20K transaction per second within one account (my test account is used only for my performance test). 20K batches mean 200K entries. So the question is why I'm being throttled after 3K entries?

Test details:

- Azure Datacenter: West US 2.
- My location: Los Angeles.
- App is written in C#, uses [CosmosDB.Table nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/) with the following configuration: ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 250, Nagles Algorithm is disabled.
- Host machine is quite powerful with 1Gb internet link (i7, 8 cores, no high CPU, no high memory is observed during the test).

PS: I've read docs

> The system's ability to handle a sudden burst of traffic to a partition is limited by the scalability of a single partition server until the load balancing operation kicks-in and rebalances the partition key range.

and waited for 30 mins, but the situation didn't change.

**EDIT**
I got a comment that E2E Latency doesn't reflect server problem.
So below is a new graph which shows not only E2E latency but also the server's one. As you can see they are almost identical and that makes me think that the source of the problem is not on the client side.

[image: new graph]

Comment: have you seen? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443081/azure-table-storage-transaction-limitations#14655667  , also : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2014/08/02/how-to-monitor-for-storage-account-throttling/

Comment: Are you using .NET in your client? If so, have you increased ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit as the post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-performance-checklist#allservices mentions?

Comment: @MitchWheat, thanks for the links. SO link describes a very similar problem, but I don't see a solution there (((. Regarding the second link, I checked if monitoring shows any throttling errors and don't see any, but I still wonder, why latency increases as soon as my request rate goes above 2k requests per second?!

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft I do use .NET client and I increased  ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit up to 250 and disable Nagles Algorithm. My question is not about client side throtling, but more about reason of throttling on the Azure side.

Comment: I don't think it's throttling on Azure side, did you get any 503 error from storage service? High latency usually indicates client side problem.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, I tried to check hypnotizes that the issue is on the client side. And here is what I found. App can work for quite a long time (5-10 mins) with a high rate (11K request per second with 24 threads), and then within 20 seconds rate may drop to 1K. App restart doesn't help. I tried to restart it for 5 times and speed was still 10x slower (1K request). Waiting for 10 minutes and starting the app resulted in a great speed again. That leads me to think that the issue is not on the client side. Can you give some hint how to prove that issue is on the client side?

Comment: If possible, you can leverage Fiddler to interpret the responses from Azure storage service. If you can see many 503 errors, it's server side throttling.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, I don't see 503 errors, but I see huge server latency (12 secs). Could you please take a look at my edit to my post (a new graph). Thanks.

Comment: Got it, per the high server latency, it's indeed due to issues on Azure storage service. Could you consider creating a support ticket for that if possible?

Comment: Hey @davidoff were you able to close down on this issue and what was the solution for this?

Comment: Hye @ashraydimri. After chatting with Microsoft support we concluded that it was behavior by design. All performance drops were either due to planned maintenance or due to rapidly increased load. In both cases, azure was spinning up a new server and moving our data there.